# How can I change tag separator in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, tagging, separator

I want to change tag separator in a Term reference field of my content type (using Autocomplete term widget (tagging)) from "," to "+" or maybe something else (in Drupal 7) because this field needs to be filled with multi lingual (persian and english) words and the "," is "،" in persian so I want a character which is same in both of these languages to prevent user changing their keyboard input.

What shoud I do now?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal answer of my question according to [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/582534) is :
in drupal/include/common.inc file, change line
`$regexp = '%(?:^|,\ *)("(?>[^"]*)(?>""[^"]* )*"|(?: [^",]*))%x';` to
`$regexp = '%(?:^|,|،|\ *)("(?>[^"]*)(?>""[^"]* )*"|(?: [^",|،|]*))%xu';`
Now both English and Persian comma is available for separator so I will not worry about change keyboard language or not!

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Active Tags module](http://drupal.org/project/active_tags).